# Getting Current_product id in Magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.2, php-7

How to get product in product edit page...

**In model file**

**XXX\Stock\Model\ResourceModel\Edit\Grid\Collection**

```
protected function _initSelect()
{    
    parent::_initSelect();
    $order = $this->registryManager->registry('current_product');
}
```

I can't get id in this file....

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to get it in admin side product edit page ?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: you can also get it from url check url there will be one param called "Id" you can get it $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"); so you will get product id

Comment: Its not working

Comment: can you post your code where you are not able to get ID ?

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 2):

You should inject the request class to use it.

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ....//rest of parameters here
) {
   $this->request = $request;
   ...//rest of constructor here
}
protected function _initSelect()
{
    $productId = $this->request->getParam('id', false);
}
```

**Note:** Clear your generated folder if you have injected any new class. You will get id only when the product is saved. Your url will look something like this if its a product edit form

```
http://example.com/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/374/key/fe1f40f9bb9379438423a4e345134df7c64a0c122dc54cbac933f8d5a6b23548/
```

Comment: still i'm not getting

Comment: Above code is perfect and it should be working .
can you please share what error you are facing in above code ?

Comment: I have add custom tab in product edit page and custom grid for that tab using modifier.Error:Open popup ,it shows "something went wrong"

Comment: I want filter the table collection using product id